# Showing alert from a tab in "More" overflow sends me back to the previous view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I have what should be a simple operation, show an alert in a SwiftUI app that uses a TabView. However, whenever I first show an alert from a tab that was pushed to the "More" overflow screen it immediately takes me back to whatever "main tab" (non-More) I was on before.

This only happens the first time I show the alert, after that it works as expected. However, on all subsequent alerts (when it is behaving correctly) I get this output in the console

```
2021-01-07 12:19:49.289546-0700 Test App[48718:25806605] setViewControllers:animated: called on <UIMoreNavigationController 0x7fcecf826c00> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.
```

If the "Button" tab is one of the primary ones (not on the "More" screen) this doesn't happen.

This same behavior also happens with the In-App purchase popup from StoreKit, not just an Alert I launch.

How can I fix this? Is this a TabView bug?

Running Xcode 12.3

Replicated in the simulator on: iPhone 11, iPhone 12, iPad Pro

Steps to replicate (using the code below):

- Launch the app
- Go to More -> Button Tab
- Click "show alert"
- Alert is shown but view behind it immediately returned to Tab One
- Repeat the same steps and it doesn't happen again (have to re-launch the app)

[image: Animation of the issue]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let textTabs = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight"]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(textTabs, id: \.self) { name in
                Text(name).tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "circle")
                    Text(name)
                }
            }
            
            ButtonTab().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "face.smiling")
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonTab: View {
    @State var showAlert = false
    
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Button("show alert") {
                showAlert = true
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("hello"),
                  dismissButton: .default(Text("ok")))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible workaround is to maintain the selection on Button click:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let textTabs = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"]

    @State private var selection = "Two" // store selection as a `@State`
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(textTabs, id: \.self) { name in
                Text(name)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "circle")
                        Text(name)
                    }
            }

            ButtonTab(selection: $selection)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "face.smiling")
                    Text("Button")
                }
                .tag("Button") // add tag for `selection`
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ButtonTab: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @Binding var selection: String // pass selection as a `@Binding`

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("show alert") {
                showAlert = true
                selection = "Button" // (force) set `selection` here
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("hello"),
                  dismissButton: .default(Text("ok")))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, for both the alert and in app purchase popup. Strange that it's needed, but thanks for the workaround!

Comment: Although this question is two years old, yet I faced this issue. In my case I need to update the selectedTab from the view otherwise the same mentioned bug was happening. Thank you @pawello2222